captum.concept.TCAV() custom classifier
I want to change the default classifier of the captum TCAV class with a custom own to do the calculation on the GPU instead and to batch it, because as it is it is slow. With the unchanged Captum setup one gets two warnings:

"UserWarning: Using default classifier for TCAV which keeps input
both train and test datasets in the memory. Consider defining your
own classifier that doesn't rely heavily on memory, for large number of concepts, by extending Classifer abstract class"

"UserWarning: Creating a tensor from a list of numpy.ndarrays is
extremly slow. Please consider converting the list to a single
numpy.ndarray with numpy.array() before converting to a tensor."


According to the Captum-wiki and its corresponding github-issue the classifier should be exchangable with a custom one.
https://captum.ai/api/concept.html#captum.concept.Classifier
https://github.com/pytorch/captum/issues/930
ChatGPT recommands the following:
class LinearClassifier(nn.Module, Classifier):
    def __init__(self, input_dim: int, output_dim: int,device: str ='cpu') -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.device = device
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim).to(self.device)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

    def train_and_eval(
            self, dataloader: DataLoader, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Union[Dict, None]:

        optimizer = optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=0.01)
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        num_epochs = 10

        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            self.train()
            for x_batch, y_batch in dataloader:
                x_batch, y_batch = x_batch.to(self.device), y_batch.to(self.device)
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                outputs = self(x_batch)
                loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

        # Evaluation after training
        self.eval()
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for x_batch, y_batch in dataloader:
                x_batch, y_batch = x_batch.to(self.device), y_batch.to(self.device)
                outputs = self(x_batch)
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                total += y_batch.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == y_batch).sum().item()

        accuracy = correct / total
        print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}')

        return {'accs': accuracy}

    def weights(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.linear.weight.t()  # Transpose to match C x F format

    def classes(self) -> List[int]:
        return list(range(self.linear.out_features))


The first issue is that now for a nn.Linear instead of a SkLearnSGDClassifier - linear classifier the classifier need now input and output dimensions - Dimension that assumingly come from the CAVs.

Alright, then I overwrite the captum methods custom_train_cav() so that I can instanciate the custom classifier there with the derrived dimensions:
dataloader = DataLoader(labelled_dataset, collate_fn=batch_collate)
        example_input, _ = next(iter(dataloader))
        input_dim = example_input.size(1)  # Assuming the second dimension is the feature size
        print("input_dim", input_dim)
        output_dim = len(concepts)
        print("output_dim", input_dim)

        classifier = classifier(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim, **classifier_kwargs)


But now it crashes at
loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)


Error message: "IndexError: Target 44 is out of bounds."
For some reason the DefaultClassifier can handle the very same target.  (see my other question: Captum TCAV train.py sgd_train_linear_model() Where do the weights come from?)
Please tell me I'm over complicating the set-up. I don't understand how now one else has this problem, when even captum recommands to adapt the classifier.
I tried implementing the class LinearClassifier() seen above. I looked through the captum-tcav-forks to look what other people did, but they don't seem to far away from the boilerplate-framework. I looked through the github issues.
Edited to clarify more details.
